# python optimization: [a, b, c] > [str(a), str(b), str(c)]

Tags: python, string, list

I need to turn a list of various entities into strings. So far I use:

```
all_ents_dead=[] # converted to strings

for i in all_ents:
    all_ents_dead.append(str(i))
```

Is there an optimized way of doing that?

EDIT: I then need to find which of these contain certain string. So far I have:

```
matching = [s for s in all_ents_dead if "GROUPS" in s]
```

Comment: Please update your question to explain what result you expect and explain what result you're getting.

Comment: The result that I expected is quite clearly explained. And the one I was getting is the same that I am getting from what the nice people below adviced to me. This Q is about an optimization of an already existing solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a `name = []`, then `name.append()` in a loop pattern, consider using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). A list comprehension builds a list from a loop, without having to use `list.append()` lookups and calls, making it faster:

```
all_ents_dead = [str(i) for i in all_ents]
```

This directly echoes the code you had, but with the expression inside `all_ents_dead.append(...)` moved to the front of the `for` loop.

If you don't actually need a list, but only need to iterate over the `str()` conversions you should consider lazy conversion options. You can turn the list comprehension in to a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
all_ents_dead = (str(i) for i in all_ents)
```

or, when only applying a function, the faster alternative in the [`map()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
all_ents_dead = map(str, all_ents)  # assuming Python 3
```

both of which lazily apply `str()` as you iterate over the resulting object. This helps avoid creating a new list object where you don't actually need one, saving on memory. Do note that a generator expression can be *slower* however; if performance is at stake consider all options based on input sizes, memory constraints and time trials.

For your specific search example, you could just embed the `map()` call:

```
matching = [s for s in map(str, all_ents) if "GROUPS" in s]
```

which would produce a list of matching strings, without creating an intermediary list of string objects that you then don't use anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) function. This will take your existing list, run a function on each item, and return a new list/iterator (see below) with the result of the function applied on each element.

```
all_ends_dead = map(str, all_ents)
```

In Python 3+, `map()` will return an iterator, while in Python 2 it will return a list. An iterator can have optimisations you desire since it generates the values when demanded, and not all at once (as opposed to a list).

Comment: Please explain why they should use a map.

Comment: @Soviut I really don't appreciate you editing my answers like that. You're very welcome to include your own answer

Comment: Hi and thanks! This (under Py3) returns `<map object at 0x7f6a978feb10>` instead of a list...
.

Comment: @Jewenile Yep, so that returns a `map` object - an iterator - which the docs explains. If you want it back to a list, you can call `list()` around the map object, but depending on what you want to do in the long run, it may be beneficial to keep it as a map object